# Addition a point on an elliptic curve with an integer value

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

Suppose $Q$ is a point in an elliptic curve such that $Q=dP$ and $d$ is an integer value, and $P$ is base point of that elliptic curve.  Note $Q = dP$ means that $P+\cdots+P$ for $d$ times** and since each point on an elliptic curve has two $x$ and $y$ coordinates, $Q$ has two $x$ and $y$ coordinates.  Also suppose $m$ is an integer value.  my question is: 
   **Is $Q+m$ equal to $x+m$ and $y+m$?**

Comment: How do you define $Q+m$? Where have you seen such operation?

Comment: Your statement that "every point...has *two* x and y coordinates..." looks a little odd. I guess you meant that each point on an elliptic curve is represented as a point on the plane and thus has $\,x,y-$coordinates... The real, acute problem though is what Álvaro mention in his comment..

Comment: At the first thank you for yours valuable comments. I see it in a paper that the writers of that paper showed it. but in that paper writers claimed taht (Q xor m) is equal to (x xor m) and (y xor m). http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-24712-5_11#

Comment: You better write down the part you mention of that paper (which isn't free) using LaTeX for clarity. It also isn't clear, at least to me, what does $\, x \;xor\; m\,$ could possibly mean

Comment: Masked public key is cP⊕H(pw). We assume that the 
public key cP is encoded in an uncompressed format (x,y). Accordingly,the masked public key is represented by the format (x⊕H(pw), y⊕H(pw)).

Comment: You suppose H(pw) is an integer value.

Comment: You can download it freely from http://ul.to/eev8wntm

Comment: I followed the suggested edit of Cantlog, but did not add the cryptography tag, because the question does not appear to be about cryptography in any particular way.

Comment: This is a example of ECC.